# Eclipse Modeling Framework - Do I need UML ecore files for Epsilon?

Tags: eclipse, uml, emf

I'm learning about model-to-model transformations with Epsilon at the moment. I went through some examples and now I'd like to try some things by myself. However, I'd like to use UML models as the target. For the examples you needed ecore files for the transformation. Can someone tell me where I could find ecore files for UML? Are they already included? I couldn't find anything with Google...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a UML metamodel in Ecore provided in Eclipse Modeling bundles. The FAQ is [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/MDT/UML2).

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.uml2.uml/resources) you will find references to maven poms and jar files with uml ecore.